# How to get a select element embedded in a table?

Tags: javascript

The code below shows a table with 2 rows and 3 columns.
A select list is in the last column of the first row.
I am able to get info from ID's: sn2 & car3( ID of one of the cars in the list).

This code is modified from w3schools:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h3>A demonstration of how to access a TR element</h3>

 <table>
   <tr id="myRow1">
     <td>First cell</td>
     <td id ="rr2">Second cell</td>
     <td id="car2">
 <select id="carlist">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option id ="car3" value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
 </td>
   </tr>

 <tr id="myRow">
     <td>First cell</td>
     <td id = "sn2">XYZ999 </td>
     <td>Third cell</td>
   </tr>

 </table>

 <p>Click the button to delete the first cell from the table row.</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     obj = document.getElementById("sn2");
     alert(  obj.lastChild.data  );

     obj = document.getElementById("car3");
     alert(  obj.lastChild.data  );
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I cannot get a value from the carlist of an item that is selected.

Comment: .value, not .data for the form elements, innerHTML or textContent if not. For example `document.getElementById("carlist").value`

Comment: PS: It is not common practice to put ID on options. The selected value is exposed as the `document.getElementById("idOfYourSelect").value`

Comment: good thing! There isn't any ID's in the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4nq6gny/3/) that shows you how to get the selected value.

I comes down to this:

```
// Get the SelectElement
obj = document.getElementById("carlist");
// show the Selected Value
alert(obj.value);
```

Comment: Your previous post was useful to me:
    // Get the SelectElement
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("carlist");
    // Get the selected value
    var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;
    // show the Selected Value
    alert(selectedValue);

Comment: .text is not .value and all modern browsers support the shortcut

Comment: Thanks, I just need the value but 
Is there a shortcut for :     var selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;    ?

Comment: Not in plain JS. In jQuery: `$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();`

Comment: Please check my answer containing all my comments

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the selected item in the carlist use:

```
document.getElementById('carlist').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It is `.value`, not `.data` for the form elements, `.innerHTML` or `textContent` for table cells
2. It is not common practice to put ID on options. The selected value is exposed as `document.getElementById("idOfYourSelect").value` in your case
   `document.getElementById("carlist").value`
3. To get the text of a selected option, the most compatible version in plain JS is `var sel = document.getElementById("carlist"), opt=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;` as you yourself found.
   In jQuery you can use `$("#carlist option:selected").text();` and a somewhat longer and unintuitive alternative in JS is
   `document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].querySelectorAll("option:checked")[0].text`

```js
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("bt1").onclick=function() {
        var sel = document.getElementById("carlist"), 
            optText=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text,
            optValue=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(optText+":"+optValue);
    }
    document.getElementById("bt2").onclick=function() {
        alert(document.getElementById("sn2").innerHTML);
    }

}
```

```css
 table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
 <h3>A demonstration of how to access a TR element</h3>

<table>
    <tr id="myRow1">
        <td>First cell</td>
        <td id="rr2">Second cell</td>
        <td id="car2">
            <select id="carlist">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="myRow">
        <td>First cell</td>
        <td id="sn2">XYZ999</td>
        <td>Third cell</td>
    </tr>
</table><hr/>
<button id="bt1">Selected option of row 1, cell 3</button>
<button id="bt2">Content of second row second cell</button><br/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code from

```
obj = document.getElementById("car3");
alert(  obj.lastChild.data  );
```

to

```
obj = document.getElementById("car3");
alert(  obj.value  );
```